# How do I add files to the solr index in Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, files, search

I'm using **Drupal 6, Solr 4.9.0 and  Apache Solr module v 6.x-3.x**.  I'm trying to use Solr to index files attached to nodes, but it's not working.  I'm using the Solr Attachments module but I know it's not compatible with 6.x-3.x since that uses the new Solr API of the Drupal 7 version.

Here's what I tried to do so far, and you'll have to pardon me if it looks bad because I'm new to the Solr API:

In apachesolr_attachments.module I changed apachesolr_attachments_update_index this is the code in the do while loop:

```
 $rows = apachesolr_index_get_entities_to_index($env_id, 'node',   $cron_limit);
 $documents = array();
   foreach($rows as $row){
     apachesolr_attachments_add_documents(&$documents, $row->entity_id, 'apachesolr_attachments');
    }
    $success = apachesolr_index_send_to_solr($env_id, $documents);
```

The function `apachesolr_attachments_add_documents` is the same, and it populates an array of "documents" that are fed to `apachesolr_index_send_to_solr`.

During a quick test when I killed the process quickly with a die command after the first cron batch it seemed to work, but letting it run doesn't work.  The search results don't return

If there's a better way, I'd appreciate anyone's help in pointing me to it.

Thanks